# Collapse an ExpansionTile when the other is expanded - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an `ExpansionTile` which I need to collapse as soon as another one is expanded (clicked), the problem is, I was able to find a solution using `ExpansionPanel` and `ExpansionPanelList`, but I actually need to use the `ExpansionTile`. I've literally tried everything, could somebody please help me figure this out? This is a minimal example of my code (just a simple example of an `ExpansionTile`):

```
ExpansionTile(
 title: Container(),
 subtitle: Container(),
 children: <Widget> {
   Container(),
 }
)
```

Comment: It is not possible. There are few workaround here but they will break the animation.. The only way is to go long way and make your own  tile from scratch